# How can I reverse a Bitcoin transaction mistakenly sent to the wrong address?

Tags: revert-transaction

I bought a bitcoin cash at a place called Bithumb in Korea and mistakenly copied the bitcoin address and sent it to the wrong. Obviously my fault is, but the fact that I can't get the cancellation done and lose all that money is very upsetting now.

Bitcoin, return my money right away. The money will not be sent anywhere, but it does not make sense that no refund is available.

```
2019. 5. 22. 13:20:14 BCH 20.121968
BitSumTXID:
7553dfd8ce04b2f78889224434f6602070c0ccdf81fb38a9e18307809d10d553

Id: 010  7122  1223

33zQhR8VGnHrXZuq4qz89VMqiWdCnPE51R
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Bitcoin Cash is not Bitcoin. Secondly, neither Bitcoin nor Bitcoin Cash have any sort of central authority or way to reverse/refund transactions. This is completely intentional - all confirmed transactions are final. The only way you can get a "refund" is to ask the person that you sent the Bitcoin Cash to to send it back to you. If you don't know who you sent it to or how to contact them, then unfortunately your money is gone.

The whole point of cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash is that it is like digital cash - once you hand someone cash in person, there's no way to get your money back except by talking to that person and asking them (or forcing them) to give you your money back. If you have no way to contact that person, then your money is gone.

Comment: So do I have to contact number 1 when I move from number 1 to number 2? Or should I call number two?

Comment: Who are number 1 and number 2? You need to contact the owner of the address you sent to. Whoever that is is up to you to figure out.

Comment: @Jihoon: as Andrew says - contact the recipient if you know who they are. You are relying on the recipient's kindness and good will to rectify your mistake.